# MSAccess Events error that's only triggered sometimes and not others

Tags: ms-access, events, event-handling

I have an access database with a fairly complex form on it.
Almost always when I open the form (it's set to default when the database is opened), the events don't work. For a tab control for example, I get:

> The expression On Change you entered as the event property setting produced the following error:
> *The expression may not result in the name of a macro, the name of a user-defined function, or [Event Procedure]
> *There may have been an error evaluating the function, event or macro.

The above is from a Tab Control `OnChange` Event, but same is happening for an option group `AfterUpdate` Event.

What's strange is, if I open the VBA editor to view the code / check the functions are correctly named, it starts working and will work fine from then on until I close the database (even if I close the VBA editor).
That would suggest that the code can be triggered correctly but for whatever reason, isn't on initially opening the database.

Anyone have any suggestions for a fix? I need this to be used by other people and they won't want to have to open the code every time.

Comment: The names might be ok but "There may have been an error *evaluating*..." Set a breakpoint on the form's load and open events, or other, step through and evaluate.

Comment: Are there any AutoExec macros? Something running when the db opens?

Comment: @wazz good point - but wouldn't a real error evaluating mean that it consistently wouldn't work even after opening the code editor?

Comment: Probably, but it depends. Open and Load events might not be the best to check. Just an idea to start troubleshooting with breakpoints. Really hard to guess this without seeing inside. I think I've seen this before but it's been a while. Sry, can't remember details. TBH, I can't remember if breakpoints work when DBs are opened. Prob not.

Comment: Did you try to decompile and compact the database? Commandline of `msaccess.exe` enhanced by `/decompile /compact`.

Comment: I don't think breakpoints are normally saved when db is closed, although I have read that they can sort of - mark won't be there but code stops where a breakpoint was once set. Might have to temporarily include Stop or Pause lines in the code to debug when opening. Try a new form as default with the same code for Tab and Option Group and see if get error.